# Calculate Longitude and Latitude, using distance and reference point

Tags: c#, google-maps, gis

First of all I have Latitude and Longitude of one point i.e. the starting point.
Second I have a distance covered and direction of distance covered. 
Now I need to calculate the new Latitude and Longitude. What is the formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this web page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) (the second calculator) - reproduced below:

[image: calculation]